# auto clicker and auto key press in javascript console

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, keyevent

i need a little help. i want to make something that you put in console and it press Enter bottom for 2000 times  and auto click  for 2000 times ***with no delay*** ! and a  key for stop this action. anyone can help me ? thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
function enter_key(ctrl, alt, shift, which) {
    var e = $.Event("keydown");
    e.ctrlKey = false;
    e.altKey = false;
    e.shiftKey = false;
    e.which = e.keyCode = 13;
    $(document.documentElement || window).trigger(e);
}
var stop = false;
for (var i=0; i<2000; ++i) {
   if (!stop) {
       enter_key();
   }
}
```

click is simpler:

```
var stop = false;
for (var i=0; i<2000; ++i) {
   if (!stop) {
       $('button').click();
   }
}
```

and you can stop the iteration by setting:

```
stop = true;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . i want something that just click that i should not set id or name of tag want to click. i want something that just click!

Answer (score 0):

i thing about this and i found a code that click on the specific position :

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked')
}, false);

var support = true;

try {
    if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: false}).bubbles !== false) {
        support = false;
    } else if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}).bubbles !== true) {
        support = false;
    }
} catch (e) {
    support = false;
}

setInterval(function() {
    if (support) {
        var event = new MouseEvent('click');
    }else{
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    }
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
},1000);
```

and i found this code for get mouse position :

```
function FindPosition(e) {
    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY)     {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
        posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
            + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
            + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    // posx and posy contain the mouse position relative to the document
    // Do something with this information
}
```

so how can i use this code to import mouse position in auto click code ???

Comment: Asking the question in the answer is not good idea, you should ask another question.